# Are there published guidelines, standards, or references that propose more than 80 chars per line?

Tags: coding-style, code-formatting

Despite increases in screen size and resolution, [many sources](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Line_length) still suggest that code be limited to 80 characters per line. I realize than there are many different opinions on this subject, but I wonder whether there are any standards bodies or influential firms that use other limits (120 characters is a common alternative). For example, are any standards bodies considering "enlarging" the suggested limit? Are there large scale software projects (e.g. at NASA or ESA) that use larger limits?

> Note: This is not yet another question about what [individuals do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724945/should-we-keep-80-characters-per-line-in-java), or
>   about [related opinions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5471791/656912), though I'd welcome such information as
>   *comments*. This is a specific question about whether there is any indication that standard practice or recommendations (in the form of
>   specific examples) is likely to change soon.

Comment: Fun fact, the actual 80-character terminal limit predates to old punch cards having 80 columns... which dates back as far as 1928 thanks to IBM's 80-column card format.

Comment: As requested, here is an opinion as a comment.  I work in terminals, and like to have as many terminals floating around as I conveniently can so I can be looking at multiple things.  I therefore would like code to be relatively "narrow".

Comment: Our company internally uses 120 characters, because we know all developers have big enough screens (and usually 2). For _published_ guidelines, it's not so easy to know what hardware the developers have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Android style guide](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#limit-line-length) says

> ## Limit Line Length
>
> Each line of text in your code should be at most 100 characters long.
>
> There has been lots of discussion about this rule and the decision remains that 100 characters is the maximum.
>
> Exception: if a comment line contains an example command or a literal URL longer than 100 characters, that line may be longer than 100 characters for ease of cut and paste.
>
> Exception: import lines can go over the limit because humans rarely see them. This also simplifies tool writing.

Chromium also uses these style guidelines, and I believe Guava uses something similar.  All of these are derived at some point from Google's internal style guide which allows 100 columns.  For example, the [eclipse rule set](http://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/source/browse/trunk/eclipse-java-google-style.xml) from code.google.com/p/google-styleguide includes:

> ```
> <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.lineSplit" value="100"/>
> ```